# Writing, displaying, and storing Japanese characters in c#

Tags: c#

I am working on a project which requires lots of japanese katakana, hiragana, and kanji characters. The original files are excel files using the "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック" font. The problem I am having seems to be the same as everyone else with this type of issue and c#. The solutions I have found all seem to start with adding the text within the c# program. 
What I am trying to do is read one of my .xls or .txt files that I have made into c#, work with the data using normal c# functions such as string compare. However, when I do this, noting happens. Writing or displaying the data produces "?" marks. Nothing new here.

I tried the same idea with c++ and it works perfectly.

The problem is it has to be c#, not c++ in order to work with the interops for the other software I am utilizing.

Long story short, do c#(system.string) not handle unicode natively compared to c++ (c string)?

I am using Visual Studio C++ 2008 Express and Visual Studio C# 2010 Express.
Files are the same, but it works in c++ and not in c#.

Sorry, I haven't used english in a while.
I have tried various types, the below is the latest but still "?" marks for output.

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\smallerBunShou.txt"), Encoding.UTF8);   
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');

            listA.Add(values[0]);
           // listB.Add(values[1]);
           // listC.Add(values[2]);
        }

        int sizeOflistA = listA.Count();

        //using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\WriteLines2.txt"))
        var file = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(@"C:\WriteLines2.txt"), Encoding.UTF8);
        {
            foreach (string line in listA)
            {
                // If the line doesn't contain the word 'Second', write the line to the file. 
                if (!line.Contains("Second"))
                {
                    file.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have also tried the Encoding.Unicode, etc. 
My computer is a japanese PC, software is mostly japanese. According to one of the answers so far, it is not a unicode issue, Japanese PCs use Shift-JIS which is most likely what I need to look into. When I solve this I will post my solution.

Update:
After looking around a bit, I found the Shift-JIS encoding scheme.

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(932));
```

This solved my problem! Thank you @EricFalsken for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: C# has full Unicode functionality. Your question really makes no sense like this. "Nothing new"? Well, to me, it is very new that C# is supposed to have problems with Unicode. The problem most likely is in the reading part of your application. You should change your question significantly by telling us what exactly the problem is and by showing the relevant code.

Comment: Are the characters shown correctly in Excel?
You can set the Font of your form. Or you can create SatteliteAssemblies with the translation and let them be loaded by swithcing UICulture.

.Net uses the system language and font for this language by default.

Comment: What code are you using to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you're using the wrong encoding when transforming between bytes and string. C# uses UTF-16 internally and modern software should encode text files with UTF-8. No idea what your excel/txt files use. Perhaps they're based on some legacy encoding, such as Shift-JIS.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I am sorry I was not very clear, what I meant by "Nothing new" was during my research into this, other people were having the same or similar problem. I tried the solutions for these but I still get the same results. However the answer below about japanese computers do not use unicode, is pointing me in a new direction for my research.

Comment: I'm just puzzled at people throwing -1's around like there's no tomorrow. I'd really appreciate the -1ers to explain why. Btw, I just +1'd the post to completely offset the three members who -1'd this OP.

Comment: I wonder that your code didn't throw any exception, because if utf-8 is expected and the input is not utf-8, usually invalid startbytes and/or following bytes are detected (invalid sequences).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normal .txt files are not saved in Unicode format. You're going to need to specify the byte format when reading the FileStream by running it through the TextReader and Encoding.Unicode.

But note that most Japanese computers and documents do NOT use Unicode. They still use Shift-JIS quite extensively.

I can assure you that all strings in C# support Unicode natively.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I am using a Japanese computer, with mostly japanese software. I am sorry I forgot to mention that. I will look into the Shift-JIS next.

Comment: Found it! the encoding scheme for Shift-JIS is Encoding.GetEncoding(932)); This solved my problem, thank you!